# Include Intent extra when using recreate()

Tags: android, android-intent, workflow, recreate

I'm trying to recreate() and activity on Android.  I need additional data to be passed via an Intent to the recreated activity.  How can this be done?

The following code does not work.

```
getIntent().putExtra("flag",true);
recreate();
```

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(MessageService.this, ViewMessageActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("message", "value");
    startActivity(i);

Then in the activity you can retrieve like this:

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String message = extras.getString("message")

Comment: or try this one Intent intent = getIntent(); finish(); startActivity(intent);

Comment: use saved state for that

Comment: @blaffie Were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `recreate()` and save your date into `SharedPreferences`. In this way you are free to do many things and also the previous activity is completely destroyed before NewActivity begin. Take a look at [this deep StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056676/8383332).

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you restart activity via Intent :

```html
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("your","params");
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: probably because in the context he cannot start a activity