# onStop delays to be called when restarting activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

When restarting an Activity, `onStop()` from previous activity delays too much to be called.

I am using this code to restart my activity **PlayerActivity.java**

```
Intent playerIntent = getIntent();
playerIntent.putExtra(Constants.VIDEO_ID, videoId);
playerIntent.putExtra(Constants.CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
playerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
startActivity(playerIntent);
```

Let's call **PreviousPlayerActivity** and **NewPlayerActivity**, the activity that was before and the new activity. (remembering that they are the same PlayerActivity).

**Sequence**

When restarting the app follows this flow in the activity-lifecycle.

```
PreviousPlayerActivity onPause() --> 
NewPlayerActivity onCreate() --> 
NewPlayerActivity onStart() --> 
NewPlayerActivity onResume() --> 
NewPlayerActivity performs a heavy operation --> 
PreviousPlayerActivity onStop() --> 
PreviousPlayerActivity onDestroy()
```

**What I need**

I need PreviousPlayerActivity to be completed destroyed before NewPlayerActivity starts. However, `onStop()` is just called after the heavy operation, so it delays around 10 seconds to be called.

**What I tried**

If I use `recreate()` method it does destroy PreviousPlayerActivity before calling NewPreviousActivity, but by calling `recreate()` I can not putExtras into the new activity instance.

**Questions**

1. How to completely destroy PreviousActivity when restarting an activity?
2. Is there a way to putExtras while using `recreate()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) from Android Developer guide.

> **Coordinating activities**
>
> When one activity starts another, they both experience lifecycle
>   transitions. The first activity stops operating and enters the Paused
>   or Stopped state, while the other activity is created. In case these
>   activities share data saved to disc or elsewhere, it's important to
>   understand that the first activity is not completely stopped before
>   the second one is created. Rather, the process of starting the second
>   one overlaps with the process of stopping the first one.
>
> The order of lifecycle callbacks is well defined, particularly when
>   the two activities are in the same process (app) and one is starting
>   the other. Here's the order of operations that occur when Activity A
>   starts Activity B:
>
> 1. Activity A's **`onPause()`** method executes.
> 2. Activity B's **`onCreate()`**, **`onStart()`**, and **`onResume()`** methods execute in sequence. (Activity B now has user focus.)
> 3. Then, if Activity A is no longer visible on screen, its **`onStop()`** method executes.
>
> This predictable sequence of lifecycle callbacks allows you to manage
>   the transition of information from one activity to another.

So the behavior that you describe is expected or predictable.

Back to your questions.

> 1.How to completely destroy PreviousActivity when restarting an activity?

- Using [recreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) API, **the limitation is it only works from API 11 or above**

> 2.Is there a way to putExtras while using recreate()?

- From [recreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) documentation

> **recreate**
>
> ```
> public void recreate ()
> ```
>
> Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results
>   in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a
>   configuration change -- the current instance will go through its
>   lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.

Because the activity will be recreated so [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) will be called as well. As you can guess the idea is save data in `onSaveInstanceState` and retrieve in `onRestoreInstanceState` or `onCreate`.

Step 1: Save data in `onSaveInstanceState`

```
// The key for saving and retrieving isActivityRecreated field.
private static final String KEY_IS_ACTIVITY_RECREATED = "KEY_IS_ACTIVITY_RECREATED";

/** true if this activity is recreated. */
private boolean isActivityRecreated = false;

// Call this method when you want to recreate this activity.
private void recreateActivity() {
    isActivityRecreated = true;
    recreate();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_ACTIVITY_RECREATED, isActivityRecreated);
    outState.putInt(Constants.VIDEO_ID, videoId);
    outState.putInt(Constants.CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
}
```

Step 2: Retrieve the data in `onRestoreInstanceState` or `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isActivityRecreated = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_ACTIVITY_RECREATED);
        if (isActivityRecreated) {
            // This activity has been recreated.
            // Reset the flag
            isActivityRecreated = false;

            // Write your code when this activity recreated.
            int videoId = savedInstanceState.getInt(Constants.VIDEO_ID);
            int categoryId = savedInstanceState.getInt(Constants.CATEGORY_ID);
            ...   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by setting a noHistory flag as true in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I think you don't need to keep that activity state when minimizing according to your requirement.

```
<activity
            android:name=".PlayerActivity"
            android:noHistory="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Lucefer. Your answer does make sense, but unfortunately, it kept the same behavior.